# I cant find bootstrap data-target, data-toggle options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

im using Abobe Dreamweaver CC and bootstrap v3.1.1 but i don't get **data-toggle** or **data-target** options. I tried different versions of bootstrap but they didn't solve my problem. 
What is wrong?

Comment: and your problem is....?

Comment: getting data-toggle and data-target options

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the dreamweaver auto-complete feature??
If not, then just type in say, **data-toggle: collapse** and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If Andrew Lyndem is right, and you're talking about autocomplete - tell us if you're using local files of bootstrap. If no - you should. Then it's more possible for you to have these options.

If you don't know whether they local or not - provide us a code snippet of including bootstrap files.

I'll try to help.